# how to restart teamcity server

Tags: teamcity, restart, teamcity-9.0

I am a beginner to teamcity. Our Teamcity 9 server stopped working after I installed Gradle. I doubt that it was problem with port or something like that. I removed Gradle but Teamcity didn't work. So I tried to restart Teamcity server. We have two teamcity agents. I stopped agents with:

```
sudo ./runAll.sh stop
```

and I stopped the server with `sudo ./shutdwon.sh`
after that I started server again with `./startup.sh` and agents with

```
sudo ./runAll.sh start
```

Now when I am writing url address in browser I am getting either connection_timout or connection refused But when I am writing url with explicit IP address like 10.31.24.18:8111 then I am getting  [image: Create Administrator Page]
My questions:

1- How can I restart Teamcity and agents so that I am getting same agents and project as before restart in TeamCity UI? Or If I am creating Administrator account now after that I should reconfigure all projects or my projects before restart will be there?

2- Why URL with IP-address is working but URL with domain name server name is not working?

Comment: Server restart shouldn't force you to create new admin account. You have to take a look at `teamcity-server.log` to see what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

You can restart TeamCity right from the UI: `Administration` > `Diagnostics` > `Server Restart`. You will need to have server admin permissions for that.

Answer (score 1):

using command line

```
cd /opt/teamcity/bin
(sudo) ./teamcity-server.sh stop
(sudo) ./teamcity-server.sh start
```